# Proof using deductive system and modus ponens

Tags: propositional-calculus

The axioms, if p and q are two sentences

> p$\Rightarrow$(q$\Rightarrow$p)
>
> (p$\Rightarrow$(q$\Rightarrow$r))$\Rightarrow$((p$\Rightarrow$q)$\Rightarrow$(p$\Rightarrow$r))
>
> (~q$\Rightarrow$~p)$\Rightarrow$(p$\Rightarrow$q)

using these axioms and Modus Ponens how to prove

> ~a$\Rightarrow$(a$\Rightarrow$b)

When i start with axiom two,

> p as ~a ,
>
> q as ~a$\Rightarrow$(a$\Rightarrow$b) and
>
> r as ~a

end up with no solution.

How to approach these kind of proofs?

Answer (score 0):

We can use the *Deduction Theorem* : with it, we can easily get the "derived rule" of *Syllogism* :

> $A \to B, B \to C \vdash A \to C$.

---

Now for the main proof :

1) $\lnot A \to (\lnot B \to \lnot A)$ --- Ax.1

2) $(\lnot B \to \lnot A) \to (A \to B)$ --- Ax.3

> 3) $\lnot A \to (A \to B)$ --- from 1) and 2) by *Syllogism*.

---

We can get rid of the *Deduction Th* with the following derivation of *Syllogism* :

1) $A \to B$ --- premise

2) $B \to C$ --- premise

3) $(B \to C) \to (A \to (B \to C))$ --- Ax.1

4) $A \to (B \to C)$ --- from 2) and 3) by *modus ponens*

5) $(A \to (B \to C)) \to ((A \to B) \to (A \to C))$ --- Ax.2

6) $(A \to B) \to (A \to C)$ --- from 4) and 5) by *modus ponens*

> 7) $A \to C$ --- from 1) and 6) by *modus ponens*.

Answer (score 0):

I use Polish notation and condensed detachment.

```
axiom 1 CpCqp
axiom 2 CCpCqrCCpqCpr
axiom 3 CCNpNqCqp
D1.3  4 CpCCNqNrCrq
D2.4  5 CCpCNqNrCpCrq
D5.1  6 CNpCpq
```